# c# How to put a constraint on a generic Func argument that is within a method signature

Tags: c#, generics

```
public void Test<TFeature>(Func<TController, ViewResult> controllerAction)                                          
            where TController : IController
            where TFeature : ISecurityFeature
        {
            ...
        }
```

I'm getting the error, *Test does not define type parameter TController*.  How can I put a constraint on TController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are defining it inside `SomeClass<TController>` (in which case you need to put constraint next to `class SomeClass<TController>`), you need to make `TController` a generic argument of your function, i.e.:

```
public void Test<TFeature, TController>(Func<TController, ViewResult> controllerAction)                                          
            where TController : IController
            where TFeature : ISecurityFeature
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: looks like we answered that almost at the same time, good point mentioning the fact that the class could define the TController type.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the TController as a generic parameter too

```
public void Test<TFeature, TController>(Func<TController, ViewResult> controllerAction)                                          
        where TController : IController
        where TFeature : ISecurityFeature
    {
        ...
    }
```